# Why is my Texture on the opposite side of the normals

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, normals

The image texture is showing up on both sides of the model however the bump map, reflection map, roughness map, etc are all on the opposite side that the normals are facing. I removed the top face of the model to show whats going on (the gloss on the interior is the texture). If I flip the normals then the texture shows up on the correct side however the normals are then facing the wrong direction. I tried adding a solidify modifier, same problem. I also added double sided normals and nothing changed. What is going on?[image]

Comment: This is the regular default behavior, you can't apply a material only to the front of a face, materials are always applied to the back and front faces of a model, unless you mask them with some sort of normal input.

Comment: I know which is why im confused as to why its only applying the textures to the back face

Comment: I see them both in back and front of your faces in your screenshot, I don't understand what you mean. What exactly were you expecting to see? Also have in mind that Cycles material and texture preview in the viewport is meant as a basic reference, it is not by any means representative of the final result, nor does it attempt to be.

Comment: The diffuse jpg is shown appropriately however the additional normal, gloss, and reflection map is not. The white streak on the interior of the box (a light reflection) does not show on the exterior of the box unless the normals are flipped to face the wrong way. I changed the image to show what I mean better.

Comment: What you are seeing is not a light reflection, the viewport representation is not able to generate or display light interactions of any sort at this point (reflections, shadows, gloss or otherwise. What you are seeing is most likely the result of the normal map causing issues when viewed from the backside of the face, causing anomalies with normal directions. Not sure there is any way around, though this normally would never be visible and likely doesn't happen in rendered view anyway. Your model also seems to have some bad topology and lots of ngons which are common source of trouble.

Comment: I figured out why I thought the texture was having no effect and it was because the normal map strength was at 0 I appreciate the help man!